# How to get the text in array and compare the value with data in excel in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, excel, selenium

Code used:

```
 int n = 0;
   int a[10] = null;
       for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
                a[i] = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='steplist']/li[n]")).getText();
                 System.out.println("/userID ="+a[i]);
             }
```

Please help me to convert string and int , and how can I get all the values of li and store it in n ?

Comment: You can not convert webelement to String or int

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the elements that have the same xpath using findElements instead of findElement so you can do something like this:

```
WebElement elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='steplist']/li"))
for(WebElement elem: elements) {
    a.add(elem.getText());
}
```

For the excel you can use jexcelapi